# Can I use Jenkins XCode Plugin to build an iPad project on Linux System?

Tags: xcode, jenkins, xcodebuild

Can I use Jenkins XCode Plugin to build an iPad project on Linux System?
Only Compile and generate the ipa file for continuous build

Comment: No, you can't.  It's probably best to use OSX Server.

Answer (score 2):

The Jenkins XCode Plugin will only work properly when run on system with Mac OSX and XCode installed.  The system in question can be either the Jenkins master or a slave agent.

In the case of the original poster, using a Linux Jenkins Master with a Mac OSX+XCode slave where the Mac slave handles the build of the job - that will work.

Comment: It means that I can use a Linux System as Master and a Mac OSX as slave,let the master trigger the slave to build,right?

Comment: Correct.  Updating answer to reflect this.